# Line break after every "."

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I am using Axios to get data from an API. Then I am presenting the user with the data. The problem is that the text can be very lengthy and I wanted to add a line break after every "." for better presentation. Does anyone know a way to do it with CSS or any other way? Thank you. I'm using javascript by the way.

I am trying your code and my data is still not getting modified.
Am I making a mistake? I am new to js.

```
function App() {
  const [cardChosen, setCardChosen] = useState(false);
  const [cardName, setCardName] = useState("");
  const [card, setCard] = useState({
    passageName: "",
    passages: "",

  });

  const searchCard = () => {

    //this has been changed from the original
    Axios.get(`https://bible-api.com/${cardName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setCard({
        passageName: cardName,
        passages: response.data.text,
        passage: card.passages.replaceAll('. ', '.\n')
      });

      setCardChosen(true);
    });
 //   addNewLines(card.passage);
  };

  // const addNewLines = () => {
  //   card.passage = card.passage.replaceAll('. ', '.\n');
  // };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="TitleSection">
        <h1>Bible passages</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange= {(event) => {
          setCardName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={searchCard}>Search the Bible</button>
      </div>
      <div className="DisplaySection">
        {!cardChosen ?
        (<>
        <h3> Please write the passage you want to read.</h3>
        <h6>Format example: john 3:16</h6>
        <h6>If you want several passages, write: john 3:1-16</h6>
        </>)
        :
        (
        <>
        <h1>{card.passageName}</h1>
        <h4>{card.passage}</h4>
        </>
        )}

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I posted the entire code now so you can see what card is, basically card is the user input, or the passage they wanna read

Comment: Try removing the space chars behind the dots `'. '` -->  `'.'`?

Comment: @nscoelho apply `white-space: pre` css rule to the element where you are rendering `passage`.  `\n` doesn't work without this rule. You can check the answer I wrote below

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data as a string in javascript you can do this:

```
const myString = 'Hello, this is a string with one line. It will soon have 2 lines.'
const stringWithNewLines = myString.replaceAll('.', '.\n');
```

This will replace all occurrences of periods with a period followed by a new line (the \n is a newline). The new string is now:

```
Hello, this is a string with one line.
 It will soon have 2 lines.
```

Notice there is a space at the start of the second line now, because there is a space following the period. If you want to get rid of the space do

```
const stringWithNewLines = myString.replaceAll('. ', '.\n');
```

So now it is replacing the space as well.

Note that `replaceAll` returns a new string and does not modify the original string.

I am fairly sure there is no way to do this in CSS, but if your string is already in javascript it will be very easy.

Comment: I am using your code and yet my data is not getting modified. Am I making a mistake?  const searchCard = () => {

    //this has been changed from the original
    Axios.get(`https://bible-api.com/${cardName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setCard({
        passageName: cardName,
        passage: response.data.text,

      });
      addNewLines(card.passage);
      setCardChosen(true);
    });
  };

  const addNewLines = (passage) => {
    card.passage = card.passage.replaceAll('. ', '.\n')
  }

Comment: @nscoelho Yes there is an error in there. Your function shows `addNewLines` is bugged. Do this `const addNewLines = (card) => { card.passage = card.passage.replaceAll('. ', '.\n') }`. Also, when you're calling the function, pass the card in itself instead of `card.passage` like this `addNewLines(card)`.  If you pass the `passage` string in directly you will not be able to modify it like that within the function. However, if you pass the `card` variable to the function and modify the passage within the card that will work like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add modify the text adding `\n` after each `.`  (dot and space) with javascript.

```
const textFromAPI = 'Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit.';
const modifiedText = textFromAPI.replaceAll(/\. /g, '.\n');
```

After that, you should put the text inside an element that has `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;` CSS rule. [More about white-space rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```html
<div style="white-space: pre;">
 <!-- modifiedText goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using the regular expression here instead of simply `'. '`?

Comment: @YungGun I don't think there is. Probably I thought I was using `.replace`, not `.replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in multiple ways, two of them are using:

1. `string.prototype.split( )` and `array.prototype.join( )`

   `text = text.split('.').join('. <br/>');`
2. `string.prototype.replace( )`

   `text = text.replace(/\./g, '. <br/>');`

Please execute this snippet below. I've added some css, you can ignore it.

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum congue, enim sit amet dictum varius, purus massa tempus eros, eu porttitor magna tellus vel quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque sit amet placerat tortor, a euismod tortor. Phasellus eget placerat nisl, sit amet aliquet felis. Nulla lacus est, euismod vitae aliquam ut, mollis at odio. Cras tempor volutpat tellus, id sagittis orci mollis ut. Nulla aliquam mattis tortor. Curabitur lacus erat, ultrices in tempor sit amet, scelerisque sed risus. Nunc ultrices vulputate nisi, eu pulvinar neque laoreet auctor. Nunc ullamcorper nec enim in tincidunt. Duis sit amet viverra tellus, eu ultrices orci.';

const element = document.querySelector('.text');

//Either This
//text = text.split('.').join('. <br/>')

//or This
text = text.replace(/\./g, '. <br/>')
element.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');

.text{
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
color:#ffeaa7;
}

.card{
border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
background-color: #2d3436;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<p class="text"><p>
</div>
```